# CSV File Save Hindi Devanagari characters words Getting ,

Tags: php

I have a CSV file which contains words in english followed by  Hindi words. I am trying to read the CSV file and do some further processing with it. The csv file looks like so:

```
Vice President-1    ????? ?????? ????
Vice President-2    ? ? ?
Vice President-3    ? ? ?
Secretary   ? ? ?
```

How to read this file in php with  Hindi words i also insert that word in database , and retrive

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_path);
$file = fopen("$target_path", "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 8000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with hebrew and found out getcsv() functions don't work well with non english UTF-8.
Here is my solution (parsing csv manually):

```
$data = 'some csv string';  
$data_arr = preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $data);  
while ($line = array_shift($data_arr)) 
{
    $row  = array();
    $line = preg_match_all('/"[^"]+"|[^,]+/', $line, $matches);
    $line = $matches[0];  
//your code here  
}
```